# In jmeter SEVERE: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect exception

Tags: plugins, jmeter, mqtt, jmeter-plugins

In jemeter i am testing for 100000 MQTT concurrent user with ramp up of 10000 and loop count is 1.

The library that I am using for MQTT in Jmeter is https://github.com/emqx/mqtt-jmeter . But I am getting 
SEVERE: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect exception after reaching 64378.

Specification:
    OS: Windows 10
    Ram : 64 GB
    CPU : i7

Configuration in registry editor:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the windows having too many active client connections.

The default number of ephemeral TCP ports is 5000. Sometimes this number may be insufficient if the server has too many active client connections. In that case the ephemeral TCP ports are all used up and no more can be allocated to a new client connection request resulting in the error message (for a Java application)

You should specify TCP / IP settings by editing the following registry values ​​in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Services \ Tcpip \ Parameters` registry subkey:

1. MaxUserPort

Specifies the maximum port number for ephemeral TCP ports.

2. TcpNumConnections

Specifies the maximum number of concurrent connections that TCP can open. This value significantly affects the number of concurrent osh.exe processes that are allowed. If the value for TcpNumConnections is too low, Windows can not assign TCP ports to stages in parallel jobs, and the parallel jobs can not run.
These keys are not added to the registry by default.

Follow this link to [Configuring the Windows registry: Specifying TCP / IP settings](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSZJPZ_8.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.productization.iisinfsv.install.doc/topics/wsisinst_config_winregtcpip.html) and made necessary edit. 
Hope this will help.

Comment: I have added but then also after some connections it is giving In jmeter SEVERE: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect exception. Is it possible to have 100000 connections in jemeter with windows OS.